# Python programming : sklearn library access denied to folder error when downloading 20 newsgroups data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Getting access denied error in Python when trying to download 20 newsgroups data
Below it the stack trace of the method call and error.
sklearn is the library used to download the data by following method call.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
groups=fetch_20newsgroups()
```

Error is access is denied to following file. I have changed access 
to write access to following file but it programmatically changes back to read access and data is not downloaded.

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:
>   'C:\Users\nvishwar\scikit_learn_data\20news_home\20news-bydate-test\sci.crypt'

Full Stack trace:

```
c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3>python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
>>> groups=fetch_20newsgroups()
Downloading 20news dataset. This may take a few minutes.
Downloading dataset from https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5975967 (14 MB)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\twenty_newsgroups.py", line 215, in fetch_20newsgroups
    cache_path=cache_path)

  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\twenty_newsgroups.py", line 86, in download_20newsgroups
    tarfile.open(archive_path, "r:gz").extractall(path=target_dir)
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tarfile.py", line 2007, in extractall
    numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tarfile.py", line 2049, in extract
    numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tarfile.py", line 2121, in _extract_member
    self.makedir(tarinfo, targetpath)
  File "c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tarfile.py", line 2150, in makedir
    os.mkdir(targetpath, 0o700)
Perm`enter code here`issionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\nvishwar\\scikit_learn_data\\20news_home\\20news-bydate-test\\sci.crypt'
```

Comment: What do you mean it programmatically changes back to read access?  Do you mean the permissions are changed somewhere?

Comment: Basically I get an error "Access is denied." I am guessing that this method call changes  permission to directory scikit_learn_data  on windows to read only access.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is most certainly being downloaded, it just isn't being extracted. This isn't because of the permissions of any file, rather it is the permissions of a directory that is preventing `os.mkdir(targetpath, 0o700)` from creating the folder `targetpath`. You could either try changing those permissions, or if feasible, deleting the entire directory tree starting from `scikit_learn_data` and trying again. If that still doesn't work, you could always manually extract the files after the download.

Comment: Right. Data is downloaded but groups object is not populated with the downloaded data. If I try to call groups then I get an error saying that is is not defined.  After this methodcall  -->  groups=fetch_20newsgroups() , I will have to find out another way to populate groups object by reading downloaded files.

Comment: Deleting the directory did not help.

Comment: Does it work on a different `data_home`? Try running it as `groups=fetch_20newsgroups(data_home='~/sklearn_data')`. Also, are there any subfolders in the "20news_home/20news-bydate-test" folder?